# Angular Unit Test - How to inject dependencies to TestBed by using useValue in the TestBed provider

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, angular-test, testbed

The service I want to test has the following constructor:

```
constructor(@Inject('enviroment') environment) {
    this.initConfig(environment);
}
```

The `environment` is provided in app.module under providers by:

```
{ provide: 'environment', useValue: environment }
```

So I configured the `TestBed` as follows:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [{ provide: 'environment', useValue: testEnv }, TestService]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(TestService);
});
```

And I keep getting:

> Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[enviroment]:
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[enviroment]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for enviroment!

The code itself works fine when serving/building so I assume the mistake is somewhere on how I configured the `TestBed`? I've also tried `useFactory` to no avail.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [{ provide: 'environment', useFactory: ()=>testEnv }, TestService]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(TestService);
});
```

Comment: I would like to help with this as I have done this kind of test situation many times, but I'd need to see more of the code.  Can you provide the complete spec file and the complete component file?  Of course you can remove stuff if completely unrelated, but at least need to see the structure of the file.

Comment: nvm I think I found your issue

Comment: Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is just a typo.

It was missing the **n** in enviro**n**ment

```ts
constructor(@Inject('enviroment') environment) {
```